# Is there a way to copy mp3 files directly over to an ipod from the command line?

Tags: ipod

Can you copy mp3 files directly to an attached ipod from the command line and have them show up on the ipod for listening?

Comment: Do you have any software requirements on your computer OS or command line tools? In a nutshell, iTunes on the iPod wants the file to be listed in the library as well as stored in the correct location - so tools like PhoneView might be scriptable if you are more interested in command line than just getting the songs over and bypassing iTunes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not unless you use custom firmware (Rockbox, iPod Linux for older models). The iPod depends on a database file for playing files and if you just copy the files over they will not be in said database and subsequently the iPod will not be able to play them.